# Extract text in quotes after specific preceding text string for whole column

Tags: excel, vba, find, extract

I have a column of data and need to delete the text either side of the Company Name, leaving just the company name in that column.
The company name is always preceded with "Company","value":

Example cell data:
some text to delete,:"Company","value":"**Company name to remain**", some text to delete

Please help me with Excel VBA to accomplish this. I wouldn't know where to start with this one.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it need to be VBA?  IT sounds like you're parson some kind of JSON, not sure.

Comment: I am new to this and would prefer VBA. I can do basic stuff myself, but dont know where to start with this. The original is an exported file from a website database and would like to extract the list of company names. Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Without a decent example, mid(A1,find("value:",A1,1),find("some end point",A1,1)) may be a starting point

Comment: If the file is a JSON, there are VBA tools available that can easily parse it.

Comment: Can you show tow example of real text? I mean, are there strings between double quotes, separated by ":"? And between ":" some strings separated by comma ","?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out myself.
I broke the process down into seperate stages.
Firstly, I found it easier removing all the quotes, commas and colons from the data column.
Then used InStr to find the the Companyvalue and remove everything before it, including the Companyvalue text itself and then a similar process to remove all the text after The Company Name text that I wanted to keep.

An example cell data string:

```
{"profile":{"45":{"B":{"profile_id":"2829","description":"Company","value":"Company Name Text To Keep","section":"B","field_id":"45"}}}}
```

The VBA I used:

```
Sub ExtractCompanyName()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Replace What:=":", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Replace What:="_", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("B:B")
      If InStr(Cell.Value, "Companyvalue") > 0 Then Cell.Value = Split(Cell.Value, "Companyvalue")(1)
   Next
 For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("B:B")
      If InStr(Cell.Value, "sectionBfieldid45") > 0 Then Cell.Value = Left(Cell.Value, InStr(Cell.Value, "sectionBfieldid45") - 1)
   Next
End Sub
```

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the JSON format is fixed and you only wanted just 1 value from it, below solution uses Regex:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ExtractCompanyName()
    Const regexPattern As String = """value"":""([\s\S]{1,})"",""section"""
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Change to correct worksheet reference
    
    'Get last row in column B
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Get the value into an array for faster processing, process cell by cell is a very slow process in general and should be avoided where possible.
    Dim processRng As Range
    Set processRng = ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
    
    Dim processArr As Variant
    processArr = processRng.Value
    
    'Create Regex and parse each value in the array to extract the company name
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbScript.Regexp")
    regex.Pattern = regexPattern
        
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(processArr, 1)
        If regex.Test(processArr(i, 1)) Then
            processArr(i, 1) = regex.Execute(processArr(i, 1))(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    Next i
    Set regex = Nothing
        
    'Write the array back into worksheet
    processRng = processArr
    
    Set processRng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```